# Javascript working in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have some javascript that posts back to some vb code. I've checked to make sure that the three parameters (id, statusID, and hrNote) are all receiving values. The function works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but won't execute in Safari.

```
function updateStatus(id, statusID, hrNote) {
    try{
        $.post("/EPR_PerformanceReview/UpdateStatus",
        { PerformanceReviewID: id, StatusID: statusID, HRNote: hrNote },
        function (data) {
            if (data.ok) {
                alert(data.msg);
            } else {
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this javascript code isn't executing in Safari? I'm totally stumped. My try catch block isn't alerting me of any errors either.

Comment: Are you getting any error in web browser console?

Comment: try catch won't catch an http request failing, you have to add a handler for that to listen for the promise to fail. check out the documentation for post http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: can you create a minimal, reproducible example on fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried in Safari 8.0.3: the script worked for me. Can you run the debugger, to find out if the function is running.

If you don't know how to do it: cmd+alt+a, then click on the "debugger". You can click on line numbers to add the stop flag. Than run the script again.

Comment: Hm interesting... I should've noted that I'm using Safari on Windows. I'll try using this debugger and see if anything comes up.